# JOptionPane / Input Dialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I try to get an input from the user with this :

```
int myNumber = Integer.parseInt((String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            frame,
                            "Number you want:\n",
                            "Enter number",
                            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                            null,
                            null,
                            "5"));
```

It works well but I'm not sure that the user will enter an number in the field and I don't want a `NumberFormatException` to be thrown.

Is there a way to set a `formatter` to the `JOptionPane` (like we can for a text field with a `JFormattedTextField` with setting a `DecimalFormat`) ?

Comment: Would you like to go with [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Comment: @Smit I'm opened to all propositions =) But I want this check to be in the JOptionPane not after the user clicked "OK" on it and then apply the regEx to the String I get

Comment: I dont think it will be possible to check that user entered number or text in `JOptionPane`

Comment: @Smit Yes it's possible, check the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is no way to do it.  JOptionPane doesn't provide any means to validate its input before it closes.

One easy way around this is to use a JSpinner.  JOptionPane allows components and arrays to be used as message objects, so you can do something like this:

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10;
int initial = 5;

JSpinner inputField =
    new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(initial, min, max, 1));

int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
    new Object[] { "Number you want:\n", inputField },
    "Enter number",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, null, null);

if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    int myNumber = (Integer) inputField.getValue();
    // Do stuff with myNumber here
} else {
    System.out.println("User canceled dialog.");
}
```

You can also, as you suggested, pass a JFormattedTextField as a message object instead of a JSpinner.

Answer (score 1):

See the Swing tutorial on [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) for a way to edit the value.

Or Check out the JOptionPane API. Maybe use:

```
showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType)
```

The message can be a Swing component.

Answer (score 1):

What about giving the JFormattedTextField you want to your dialog ?

```
    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(DecimalFormat.getInstance());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field);
    System.out.println(field.getText());
```

You can also use a more elaborate component if it fits you better.